# Visualise optimization process in TensorFlow averaged over batches

Tags: python, optimization, tensorflow, tensorboard

I want to use TensorBoard to visualize the optimization process (i.e. how the loss is decreasing over the minimization steps). For that I use summaries. In the graph I have the following:

```
global_step = tf.Variable(0, dtype=tf.int64, trainable=False, name="global_step")
tf_loss = ...
tf_minimize = optimizer.minimize(tf_loss, var_list=[...], global_step=global_step)
summaries = {"mysummary": tf.summary.merge([tf.summary.scalar("loss", tf.reduce_mean(tf_loss))])}
```

Optimization process with logging of summaries then looks like this:

```
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S")
summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(("{}/{}").format('logs', timestamp), flush_secs=10)

for batch in data:
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        _, sm = sess.run([tf_minimize, summaries["mysummary"]])
        summary_writer.add_summary(sm, sess.run(global_step))
```

The problem is that so far TensorBoard is showing several points in the graph for each minimization step. However, I would like to visualize the learning process averaged over batches i.e. for each global_step I would like to see the average loss.

Is there some more convenient way of doing it then making a 1D tensor of size of the maximum number of steps and store there the averages manually?

Comment: It should work as you want given your code, since reduce_mean will indeed create only one number. Are you sure you update global_step at each minimization step ?

Comment: reduce_mean computes an average loss over a single batch. The  problem is that are multiple batches and I would like to get an average loss over all of them.